# Having issue linking with an external array declared in a header file and defined in a source file

Tags: c++, linker

I need to declare a very large n-d array. It is defined in a header file and never changes. Unfortunately compiling the main file takes a very long time, so I decided to bring it out into it's own object file.

Here is the header file tables.hpp:

```
#pragma once

namespace TABLES
{
    extern const int A[10][10][10];
    extern const int B[10][10][10];
}
```

Here is the source file tables.cpp:

```
namespace TABLES
{
    const int A[10][10][10] = {};  // use default for brevity
    const int B[10][10][10] = {};  // use default for brevity
}
```

and my main file:

```
#include "tables.hpp"

int main()
{
    printf("%d", TABLES::A[0][0][0]);
}
```

and here is my Makefile:

```
CXX = clang++
CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -g -flto -Wall -Iinclude/ 
SRC = src/
INC = include/

tables.o: $(SRC)tables.cpp $(INC)tables.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC)tables.cpp

main: main.cpp tables.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o main main.cpp tables.o
```

the tables.o compiles successfully, however I am having issues linking the tables.o to the main program:

```
undefined reference to `TABLES::A'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Makefile:30: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [refactor] Error 1
```

Comment: Does it work if you use a simple int iso an array?

Comment: Did you forget to include "tables.h" in "tables.cpp"? The compiler does not give symbols external linkage unless it's aware that you want it at the point of definition.

Comment: @JVApen it does not

Comment: Could the link-time optimizations (enabled with `-flto` flag) have anything to do with it? What happens if you remove that flag?

Comment: @molbdnilo that was it. not sure how I didn't see that. How was tables.o able to compile? I would have thought it would complain that TABLES::A is declared twice then?

Comment: If you had done `#include "tables.hpp"` in your `tables.cpp` file as suggested by @molbdrillo, I think you could have kept the `-flto` flag. You should include it nevertheless.

Comment: @john It’s declared once and defined once, which is not a problem.